# Separate title and subtitle in a string by CamelCase in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have scraped a list of titles, some of them have subtitles. Unfortunately, whenever there is a subtitle it is pasted to the title (like `paste0()`). How can I separate the two in R? I am thinking of some `regex` since the pattern is a CamelCase indicates the subtitle, like this:

```
data <- data.frame(title = "Bilder aus dem LebenWie man Universalerbe wird")

result <- data.frame(title = "Bilder aus dem Leben",
                     subtitle = "Wie man Universalerbe wird")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  separate(title, into = c("title", "subtitle"), sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")
                 title                   subtitle
1 Bilder aus dem Leben Wie man Universalerbe wird
```

`sep` here uses two look-arounds to define the split point:

- `(?<=[a-z])`: positive look-behind to assert that on the left of the split point there must be a lower-case letter, and
- `(?=[A-Z])`: a positive look-ahead to assert that on the right of the split point there must be an upper-case letter

Answer (score 2):

A naive regex can look for a lower-case followed by an upper-case,

```r
strcapture("^(.+[a-z])([A-Z].+)", data$title, proto = list(title = "", subtitle = ""))
#                  title                   subtitle
# 1 Bilder aus dem Leben Wie man Universalerbe wird
```

Answer (score 2):

With tidyr's (new) `separate_wider_regex`:

```r
library(tidyr)
separate_wider_regex(data, title, c(title = "^.+[a-z]", subtitle = "[A-Z].+"))

#  title                subtitle                                
#1 Bilder aus dem Leben Wie man Universalerbe wird
```

This is equivalent to the superseded `extract`:

```r
extract(data, title, c("title", "subtitle"), "^(.+[a-z])([A-Z].+)")
```